# ASP.NET 5 Code Analyzer Recommendation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

We're building a new ASP.NET 5 application (currently using RC1) which also has some ASP.NET 5 class library projects attached to it. Looks like the Analyze tool in Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support the new code.

We really want to be able to run some basic analysis e.g. cyclomatic complexity, maintainability, etc. What can we use to analyze our code?

Comment: Microsoft is working on implementing code analysis for .xproj projects. They should be finished soon. Maybe in the VS Update 1 Release.

Comment: Nope, but you can actually get a project.json to invoke the style analyzers during the dotnet build process see this link:
https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/DotNetCli.md

A REAL fix is expected in .net core 1.1 (fall 2016).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried NDepend? It is a commercial .NET code analyzer integrated in Visual Studio. A full-featured 14-day-trial is available for [download](http://www.ndepend.com/download).

It has built-in support for [cyclomatic complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC), proposes [many default rules](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html), and lets [edit custom code rules as C# LINQ query](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL).

Hence if you want a code rule that checks that you have no method with a *cyclomatic complexity* higher than 15 for example, you can create it as:

```
// <Name>Methods too complex</Name>
warnif count > 0
from m in JustMyCode.Methods 
where m.CyclomaticComplexity > 15 
select new { m, m.CyclomaticComplexity }
```

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*

Comment: Does NDepend have full .Net Core 1.0.0/1.0.1 support?

Comment: NDepend doesn't recognize yet project.json
it can however analyze .NET core assemblies and also PDB assuming you don't use the new Portable PDB format 
the new Portable PDB format will be supported in November, project.json and more a few weeks after

Comment: I was having trouble maybe the new Portable PDB format is a default option?

Comment: You can also generate .NET Core assemblies with the regular PDB format. As stated, the new new .NET Core Portable format will be 100% supported in November.